# Angular 12 + Chartjs 3.3.2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'left'

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

while trying to learn angular I've come across a small roadblock. I want to display data which I get from an api. But for now, I've tried to create a chart with pre-defined values, which I'll change later into the get response values.
This is the steps I took:

- npm install chart.js
- ViewChart.component.html
  `<div width="100%"><canvas id="myChartTest" width="400" height="400"></canvas></div>`
- ViewChart.component.ts

```
import { Chart, LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title);

Component({
   selector: 'app-view-chart',
   templateUrl: './ViewChart.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./ViewChart.component.scss']
})

export class ViewChartComponent implements OnInit {

   ngAfterViewInit() {

       var myChart = new Chart('myChartTest', {
           type: 'bar',
           data: {
               labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
               datasets: [{
                   label: '# of Votes',
                   data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                   backgroundColor: [
                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                   ],
                   borderColor: [
                       'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                       'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                       'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                       'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                       'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                       'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                   ],
                   borderWidth: 1
               }]
           },
           options: {
               scales: {
                   y: {
                       beginAtZero: true
                   }
               }
           }
       });

   }
```

The project get compiled without any errors.
But when I view it I get theses errors

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
> at _isPointInArea (helpers.segment.js:1278)
> at Chart._handleEvent (chart.esm.js:5876)
> at Chart._eventHandler (chart.esm.js:5855)
> at listener (chart.esm.js:5738)
> at Chart.event (chart.esm.js:3083)
> at helpers.segment.js:28
> at timer (zone.js:2561)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28654)
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405)

> core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
> at _isPointInArea (helpers.segment.js:1278)
> at getNearestItems (chart.esm.js:2523)
> at nearest (chart.esm.js:2609)
> at Chart.getElementsAtEventForMode (chart.esm.js:5621)
> at Chart._handleEvent (chart.esm.js:5872)
> at Chart._eventHandler (chart.esm.js:5855)
> at listener (chart.esm.js:5738)
> at Chart.event (chart.esm.js:3083)
> at helpers.segment.js:28
> at timer (zone.js:2561)

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be in your import of Chart. You are trying to display a `bar` chart but it has not been imported. You will need to import `BarElement` also. A shorter way to test if your chart is getting rendered or not is to only import the following:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

You can refer to the [integration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc) section of chart.js docs to understand what could have been missing or here is a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chartjs-stackoverflow?file=src/app/app.component.ts).